# Track navigation with jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I try to make a stress test with jmeter: i set up jmeter proxy to record navigation and everythings is ok.
I have some problem with a page wich has a json request called by javascript: using the jmeter proxy this request doesn't works.

With firebug I can see that the response of json request is

{"error":{"msg":"couldn't parse request arguments","code":590}}

It seems that jmeter proxy modify the parameter request.

With this error, I cannot use this page: any suggest?

Thanks
Aldo

Answer (score 0):

JMeter isn't able to execute JavaScript, you'll need to construct the request manually. Perhaps you'll need to get some parameter(s) from page source via [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). Once you figure out correct request make sure that you'll add Content-Type header `application/json` via [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)